# How to copy or get a changing value of a model property to another model?

Tags: c#, model, copy

I am creating a web app using C# MVC. I created a model named `Trip.cs` with properties as below:

```
public int ID {get; set;}
public string Destination {get; set;}
public DateTime DepartureDate {get; set;}
public string MeetPlace {get; set;}
public int NumberOfSeats {get; set;}
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
public string UserId { get; set; }
```

I created another model called `ReservedTrip.cs` identical with `Trip.cs` with the same properties.
What I  do is when the logged user clicks on the `Actionlink` named "Reserve Trip", I save this "Trip" to the `ReservedTrip.cs` and I decrease the number of property `NumberOfSeats` with 1. So in other words I  copy this "Trip" data from `Trip.cs` to `ReservedTrip.cs`. The problem is when I display in a view the data from model `Trip.cs` the number of `NumberOfSeats` changes, but in the model `ReservedTrip.cs` the property `NumberOfSeats` doesn't change. So I want the changes of property `NumberOfSeats` of model Trip.cs to change in the property `NumberOfSeats` to be changed with the same value.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think the reservation table should be much simpler, containing the trip id and the user id.  Then the number of seats taken is the count of reservations and does not need to be stored separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a design standpoint, it is better to not have a copy of any table.  A good design for this situation can be something like this.

```
public class Trip
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Destination {get; set;}
    public DateTime DepartureDate {get; set;}
    public string MeetPlace {get; set;}
    public int NumberOfSeats {get; set;}
    public int CreatedByUserID {get; set;}

    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedByUser {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<TripReservation> Reservations {get;set;}
}
public class TripReservation
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int TripID {get; set;}
    public int UserID {get; set;}

    public virtual Trip Trip {get; set;}    
    public virtual ApplicationUser User {get; set;}
}
```

then in your controller you can construct a view model with the number of seats available being

```
numberOfSeatsAvailable = trip.NumberOfSeats - trip.Reservations.Count();
```

If a reservation can reserve more than 1 seat, you can sum that from all reservations for that trip.

Example: ViewModel

```
public class TripReservationsViewModel
{
    public Trip Trip { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfSeatsAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

Example: Controller

```
public ActionResult TripDetails(int id)
{
    var trip = db.Trips.FirstOrDefault(trip => trip.ID == id);
    if (trip == null)
    {
        // Trip does not exist, 
        // Redirect the user to the trips home page
        //
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    var viewModel = new TripReservationsViewModel();

    viewModel.Trip = trip;
    viewModel.NumberOfSeatsAvailable = trip.NumberOfSeats - trip.Reservations.Count();

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Example: View

```
@model TripReservationsViewModel

<h1>Trip Details</h1>
<p>Seats available: @Model.NumberOfSeatsAvailable</p>
etc...
```

Comment: I can't use migrations for TripReservation because it doesn't have a key defined. Should I add the key property too. Also why did you remove                                                            public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
public string UserId { get; set; }                                                                                                      I need them to display users who created a trip.

Comment: I removed the user thinking it was the reservation user.  You can add that user back, and I suggest naming it CreatedByUserId or something similar to remove confusion for yourself or anyone else looking at the code in the future.

Comment: You have 2 options for the key, either a composite of Trip and User ids or a separate id for the unique reservation record.  Adding a simple id to that table is probably easier.

Comment: I have difficulty on the controller too. Can you help me with the controller too?

Comment: It should be as easy as getting the trip by id.  What difficulty are you facing?

Comment: You said construct a view model but honestly, I don't have any idea how to do it. I was trying another ways but couldn't achieve anything. I want to mention that I am just a beginner with c# mvc. If you can help me with the controller too I would appreciate it a lot. Thank you.

Comment: I believe we are getting away from the original subject of your question.  I understand being new to mvc and how challenging it can be.  There is a wealth of knowledge here on SO pertaining to MVC, I suggest googling your specific question(s) with stackoverflow in the search, as this generally gives you the best results.  I will add an example of the controller and view model to my answer.

Comment: I added some additional example, I do not have mvc where I am now, there could be errors or typos.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome.  If I have sufficiently answered your question(s), can you please mark the answer as accepted.  Thanks and happy coding!